# Error while creating SharePoint publishing page - "The file does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

While creating the page (manually) I am getting "file not found error" for the page I am trying to create. When I am checking the log the error is like -

A critical error occurred while creating a PublishingPage through PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage(string, PageLayout, SPFolder). System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file http://win-k3ov869t32r:31141/sites/Demo7/Pages/testpage.aspx does not exist.

Here *testpage* is the name of the page I want to create.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise going to the ULS logs to get further information.

I would suggest looking to see if the page layout you are creating the page against exists. If you can't find the layout thats your problem.

This could be in the hive or in the page layouts list.

Hope this helps

Many Thanks

Comment: Truezplaya thanks for your suggestion. When I checked the site-contents 'Site Pages' library was missing. This happened because the 'Wiki Page Home Page' feature was not active.

Comment: Was this the solution?

Comment: People take their own time to answer questions , if they provide an answer you should mark as answered otherwise people may not reply to another question you ask